# Image will not show through transparent object

Tags: shaders

So I imported an image using the "import images as planes" plugin. Then placed it in a box, and added a transparent cylinder in front of it.

As you can see from the screenshot the brown of the box, plus other objects shows through, but the image does not.

I am guessing there is some setting I need to adjust on the image/plane to get it to show through?

Screenshot, plus the shaders created by the plugin:

[image: broken transparency]
[image: shaders]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because the import images as planes tool sets the blend mode for the material to Alpha Blend, and you're using Eevee.

Your options are to switch to Cycles or change the Blend Mode to Opaque.

[image: Change the blend mode]

[image: Fixed]

Comment: Thanks! blend mode = opaque works for me